# How can I always get Timestamp in certain format without having to explicitly define it everytime

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

When I run a select on a timestamp I get something like:

```
2015-01-02T23:22:36.000Z, 1/7/2015 11:03:31 AM
```

In order to format properly I have to do:

```
SELECT to_char(entered, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
FROM analytics WHERE business_id = 371746;
```

which is kind of a pain, since I often just do `SELECT *` and don't specify the fields.

Is there a way to tell Postgres to always return this kind of format `'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'` from a `SELECT` without having to specify it every time?

Comment: Anyone :( would appreciate it...

Comment: x-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830307/how-can-i-always-get-timestamp-in-certain-format-without-having-to-explicitly-de

Answer (score 2):

For general preferences you have the [`DateStyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) and [`LC_TIME`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html) settings.

But it would be madness to *always* truncate fractional seconds automatically - *hiding* part of the relevant information.

A possible syntax shortcut would be to create a tiny function *once*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_ts(timestamp)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS 
$$SELECT to_char($1, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')$$;
```

Then:

```
SELECT my_ts(entered) FROM analytics WHERE business_id = 371746;
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I ended up creating a view (CREATE VIEW...)